# Spreecommerce Paypal Express checkout: Why are the item descriptions missing in the order mails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, paypal, spree-paypal-express

We are currently developing a web shop using spreecommerce and the plugin https://github.com/radar/better_spree_paypal_express

When checking out the Paypal cart is reached and contains the ordered item:
[image: paypal cart]

After ordering, the item name does not turn up in the order confirmation (neither for the customer nor the shop):

[image: confirmation mail]

What could possible be the reason for this? The order confirmation is created by Paypal, so where could the information possibly get lost?

I filed a [github issue](https://github.com/radar/better_spree_paypal_express/issues/36) with the spree extension, but otoh it looks to me like the product name really gets lost inside paypal.

UPDATE:

This is what the paypal technical customer service wrote (translated by me):

I saw that you are sending

```
paymentrequest_0_name "COPY OF Testprodukt"
```

but it should be

```
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NAMEm "COPY OF Testprodukt"
```

Now I wonder, what could be the reason for this? Where are these strings generated?

I searched the better_spree_paypal_express and paypals merchant-sdk-ruby and sdk-core-ruby gems and cannot find where the line items are assembled.

Comment: Have you styled Paypal's checkout page at all?

Comment: No. This is the default, as far as I am aware. Where do I do the sort of styling you mean?

Comment: It's in the merchant profile section of Paypal -- basically, you can add a log to your checkout page to make it feel legit. I thought you might have styled the page, and accidentally used #fff for the product descriptions or something

Comment: @RichPeck: No, the product name is really missing in the mails (and in the shops paypal backend), this is no styling issue.